# What's the difference between Thread.Sleep() and Thread.SpinWait()

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have a WinForm application that uses a BackGroundWorker to create a TCP Client and send some data to a remote server.
When the socket finish close the connection and the BGW exits from the DoWork Sub.

In the RunWorkerCompleted Sub I must to wait a packet from the remote server, so I have always running a TCP server that fills a Friend String type variable and indicates that the whole packet is received using a Boolean type variable(flag).

So I must to wait that flag to becomes True to process the data that must be in the String type variable; but I don't want to hang up the GUI so I see that exist a method called SpinWait.

So, Can this code works?

There's any way to get out if the loop if the flag doesn't to true 5 minutes later?

```
Private Sub BGW1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BGW1.RunWorkerCompleted
        While Not AckReady
            System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(500)
        End While

        'Here process the received data from TCP server

        TmrReport.Start()

End Sub
```

Another things is, How many iterations represent 500mS?

Comment: That does not work, it freezes your UI when the server is not responsive.  If you are already using a worker then you might as well have it wait for the response.

Comment: Ok, so I move the while loop to DoWork Sub and use Sleep instead of SpinWait. Am I right?

Comment: Pretty unclear to me why you want to sleep at all.  When you get the response then you're done.

Comment: @HansPassant The response from the remote server takes a while, and can vary from 5 sec. to 50 sec. So I must wait that answer to process the data and send new data to the remote server.

Comment: Well, that's what a BackgroundWorker is good for, don't let the DoWork event handler exit until you got that response.  Fwiw, BeginRead and async/await get that job done too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the documentation:

[Thread.SpinWait Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx)

> The SpinWait method is useful for implementing locks. Classes in the .NET Framework, such as Monitor and ReaderWriterLock, use this method internally. **SpinWait essentially puts the processor into a very tight loop, with the loop count specified by the iterations parameter**. The duration of the wait therefore depends on the speed of the processor.
>
> Contrast this with the Sleep method. **A thread that calls Sleep yields the rest of its current slice of processor time, even if the specified interval is zero**. Specifying a non-zero interval for Sleep removes the thread from consideration by the thread scheduler until the time interval has elapsed.

So, `Sleep` basically releases the processor so it can be used by something else, whereas `SpinWait` runs a loop that keeps the processor busy (and locked to other threads).

Comment: Ok, so during the SpinWait loop the whole server will hang up?

Comment: `SpinWait()` simply keeps the calling thread busy while it is waiting. The thread is still subject to task scheduling  `Sleep()` puts the calling thread into a sleep state and removes it from task scheduling until it wakes up.